# How to limit the selectable date range on UI for Crispy Form - forms.DateField?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

In my form declaration, I have this field:

```
effective_date = forms.DateField(required=False, label='Effective Date', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}))
```

I want to limit the selectable date range on the datepicker to be `[today - 30, today]`.

Is there a way to do it in Django crispy form? I'm using Django 1.9 with `crispy form`.

FYI I tried the  `SelectDateWidget` but it is not the UI I want. I'm looking for a component which can render this UI and support date range restriction:

[image]

Comment: Did you find this date ui ?